# Scala fold for RDD [String] acting wierd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, fold

so here's my code:

```
var exceptions: String = ""
  val count = failures.fold("0")((x1, x2) => {
    println(s"x1: $x1 and x2: $x2")
    if (x1 != "-433" && x2 != "-433") {
      (x1.toInt + x2.toInt).toString
    } else {
      println(s"before: $exceptions")
      exceptions = exceptions + ", " + "There is an exception in processing, check the logs of executors for actual information"
      println(s"after: $exceptions")
      if (x1 == "-433") {
        if (x2 != "-433") {
          x2
        } else "0"
      }else {
        if (x2 == "-433") {
           x1
        }else "0"
      }
    }
  })
```

count is a RDD[String]. the most curious thing is execptions comes out as "" at the end. Here are the logs:

x1: 0 and x2: -433

before:

after: , There is an exception in processing, check the logs of executors for actual information

x1: 0 and x2: 0

final :

Comment: Is it a duplicate of one of those questions asking for a driver variable not getting updated inside a parallelized collection? Please Read about Spark Closures. You'll get a better idea.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Am not talking about any exception being thrown. the `exceptions` variable was not getting updated. But as @philantrovert pointed its due to the driver variable being passed to a set of executors

Answer (score 0):

Spark RDD's are distributed data-structures, which means that the elements of RDD's don't live on same node and transforms on RDD's don't happen on same node.

All of your transform functions are wrapped in their closure, then serialized, then sent to executor nodes, de-serialized at executor nodes, executed at executor nodes. Wrapped closure get "a copy" of used context objects.

Even if you are running spark in local node, it runs several executors on local node and they behave in same way.

So, each execution of you function will get its own copy of `exceptions` variable. And thus your `exception` string will never get updated in way which you expect it to be.